# R PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio() generates NaN when geometric=TRUE

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance, performanceanalytics

I am struggling with `PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio()` where if I try to set the parameter `geometric=TRUE` I get NaN as the return series. If I set the `geometric=FALSE` then I get the returns calculated.

I have obviously made sure that there are no "na" or "nan" or "inf" values in the input return series and the weights series.

Any pointers?

The call is:

```
stratRets <- PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio(R = rets, weights = weights, geometric = TRUE)
```

I can't copy the return and weights dataframes here as they contain thousands of rows. I will try to come up with a smaller example to reproduce the issue and post it here shortly.

Meanwhile any quick pointers on what to check will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without the example returns, this is a hard question to answer.  I've just tried it on some stock returns which I've been tinkering with, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks lebelinoz.. I think I have figured out why. If the sum of the weights row equals to 0 then the return series is NaN when geometric=TRUE. The first 4 rows in my weights dataframe are 0 weights. So once I removed them everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to remove any rows at the beginning with weights totaling to 0.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Can you elaborate what 'weights totaling to 0'? I never thought that was theoretically viable.